# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in daterangepicker

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using a `DateRangePicker` plugin in my code.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url ?>js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url ?>js/date.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url ?>js/daterangepicker.jQuery.compressed.js"></script>

<p>
  <strong>Pickup :</strong> 
  <input type="text" id="pickupdate" name="pickupdate" class="datepicker" >
</p>
```

When I click on the textbox, I get the following error in my console:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

If anybody knows why this happens, please let me know.

Comment: You may want to put the code where you initialize the datepicker

Comment: check the view source of the page. is `base_url` a variable?

Comment: i tried every thing ,but still not displaying the date.

Comment: @undefined base_url is which we written in config.php.I know this base_url is not creating any problem

Comment: As a first thought, `Maximum call stack size exceeded` means that you loop somewhere endlessly (or at least further than the stack can bear it).  Please include the JS code where you handle the `click` event.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution. The real problem was that I was including both `date.js` as well as `daterangepicker.jQuery.compressed.js`. After closer inspection, it appears that they contain the same functionality, so I just removed `date.js` from the page. I hope this will help someone who may run into a similar problem in the future.

Comment: In my case it was a double inclusion of jQuery.fileupload script.

Comment: You are life saver. Thank you very much. datejs was my problem

Answer (score 1):

I found two fixes here: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/issues/detail?id=143

The second doesn't work for me but the first works great:

"The following code at the start of the toString() function seems to fix it and feels like a satisfactory default
if (format == undefined) format = 'u';"   (thanks to Phil)